# How to Exit() early if TSpeedButton is already Down?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have two `TSpeedButton`: `btn1` and `btn2`. Their properties are set so they act together in a group and are mutually exclusive, which means that when one button is pressed the other button is automatically unpressed:

```
AllowAllUp = False
GroupIndex = 1
OnClick = onSpeedButtonsClick
```

I have some code in `onSpeedButtonsClick()` that runs some code depending on which of the two buttons was clicked.

What I'm trying to do is to make it so that if `btn1` is currently `Down`, and the user presses this button, nothing should happen:

```
procedure frmMyForm.onSpeedButtonsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { Don't do anything if the clicked button is already currently pressed down. }
  if ((Sender = btn1) and btn1.Down) or
       ((Sender = btn2) and btn2.Down) then
    Exit();

  { ... some other code here that should only run when
    the `Down` state of the buttons changes }
end;
```

The problem is that when `btn1` is currently down and the user presses `btn2`, the `Down` property of `btn2` is set to `True` **before** `onSpeedButtonsClick()` executes, so it `Exit()`s early no matter what.

Comment: Shouldn't your code be `if ((Sender = btn1) and btn2.Down) or ...`. In your shown code you are checking if the same button is down than the one that fired the OnClick event.

Comment: @SilverWarior If a button is already `Down`, and the user presses this currently down button, I want the routine to `Exit()`. If the user presses a button that is currently up (i.e. unpressed) then I want the `OnClick()` handler to run some code.

Comment: How can user press on a button that is already down a second time? Following standard button click handling defined by the Windows that shouldn't even be possible. Perhaps in a multitouch enviroment. But not othervise since in order to be able to press on the button the second time you would have to first release your click which would change button state to `Up`. Or am I perhaps missing some crucial information about your design?

Comment: @SilverWarior That is also the behaviour I expected. I think you're confusing a `TSpeedButton` with a normal `TButton`. I'm using a `TSpeedButton`, which--with the properties I described in my question--makes the 2 buttons mutually exclusive. e.g. if I press `btn1` it will stay pressed down until I press `btn2`, then `btn2` will stay pressed down until `btn1` is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store buttons state in form field and set it in the end of event handler like this (I used bitfields)

```
bState := Ord(btn1.Down) or (Ord(btn2.Down) shl 1);
```

checking:

```
   if (bState and 1) <> 0 then  
//it would be nicer to use constants like btn1down = 1 instead of magic numbers
      btn1 WAS down before
   if (bState and 2) <> 0 then
      btn2 WAS down before
```

Comment: Ah good idea, thanks! I don't see a need to use bitshifting here, so I added this form variable: `FLastSpeedButtonPressed: TObject`, that I assign to using `Sender` from the `OnClick` handler.

Comment: Rather than using opaque bitwise logic (what does 1 and 2 mean?) you could define an enum and use that, plus a method to go from button down state -> enum result of which button is down. I would avoid the boolean bit masks and use the fundamental language items - it's simpler and clearer code.

Comment: Pretty bizarre to use magic constants and bit twiddling when the language offers so much more.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the buttons' `Tag` properties to track the desired state, eg:

```
procedure frmMyForm.onSpeedButtonsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if TSpeedButton(Sender).Tag <> 0 then Exit;
  TSpeedButton(Sender).Tag := 1;
  if Sender = btn1 then btn2.Tag := 0
  else btn1.Tag := 0;

  // code that runs when the `Down` state changes ...
end;
```